# How to call MultipartFile Spring REST URL with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

When I try to call following MultipartFile Spring REST url with my Spring Template base Test method, I got following exception. How can I make this correct. Thanks.

**Spring REST URL:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/media/uploadMultipartFile/{token}/{title}/{trailId}/{wpId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody MediaHttp uploadMultipartFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,
                                                    @PathVariable String token,
                                                    @PathVariable String title,
                                                    @PathVariable String trailId,
                                                    @PathVariable String wpId,
                                                    HttpServletResponse response)
```

**Test method:**

```
try {

        // Message Converters
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<Source>());
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

        // RestTemplate
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        // URL Parameters
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        parts.add("token", "nkc2jvbrbc");
        parts.add("title", "test mp4 file");
        parts.add("trailId", "2");
        parts.add("wpId", "7");
        parts.add("file", new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\test.mp4"));

        // Post
        MediaHttp result = template.postForObject(Constants.APPLICATION_URL + "/media/uploadMultipartFile/{token}/{title}/{trailId}/{wpId}", parts, MediaHttp.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

**Exception:**

Invalid amount of variables values in [http://test.com:8080/DMW-skeleton-1.0/media/uploadMultipartFile/{token}/{title}/{trailId}/{wpId}]: expected 4; got 0

Comment: Thanks !! Code in your question helped me to resolve my issue of 400 bad request - Rest client for Image uploading by RestTemplate.

Comment: I am having the same code, but it is giving 415 Unsupported Media Type. can you tell what I am missing here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message is pretty clear, you don't specify any path parameters for submission. You only provide a map which will be send as the body of the request.

change your call to include those parameters as the last part of the method call.

```
// URL Parameters
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parts.add("file", new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\test.mp4"));
// Post
MediaHttp result = template.postForObject(Constants.APPLICATION_URL + "/media/uploadMultipartFile/{token}/{title}/{trailId}/{wpId}", parts, MediaHttp.class, "nkc2jvbrbc", "test mp4 file", "2", "7);
```

Comment: @Deinum. Yes now I got the point. Many thanks for your worth full answer. Have a nice time !